# (WP7.5)e.ChosenPhoto issue

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

my code are as follows

```
private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
  if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
  {
    Stream stream = e.ChosenPhoto;
    int len = (int)stream.Length;

    byte[] PhoteBytes = new byte[len];
    stream.Read(PhoteBytes,0,len);
   }
}
```

I am wondering is it possible to convert
byte array(PhoteBytes in this example)
to WriteableBitmap?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I thought it would be a real good question about transfering it into bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WritableBitmap bitmap = new WritableBitmap(); //Use appropriate constructor
bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
```

EDIT: You'll have to use the appropriate constructor. In one `WriteableBitmap(Int32, Int32)` constructor you can specify the bitmap width and height. See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347331%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks.Is it possible to resize the writeablebitmap if I load from Camera roll?

Comment: Sorry the constructor in the code is not accurate. See my edit.